# How to find a upper and lower bound of code?

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I have some code and the text is

For following code, find a lower and upper bound if data for function f,g is given, and we know that is best and worst case is given, condition is fulfilled in most cases.

f:O(log(n)), and lower bound is 1

g:O(n) and lower bound is (logn)^2

I think that first line of my code is logn, then since n>log(n) I think that second line is O(n*log(n))and the last lines is nlogn I think because if I use summarization I get logn(n+(logn)^2-1) end then the O is O(n^2(logn)^2). And for lower bound is n(logn)^3 i am beginner in this so please tell me where I make a mistake. Thank you

```
for(int i=n;i>0;i/=2)
if(f()<=g())
for(int j=f()*f();j<n;j++)
f()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is badly formatted so it is not really clear what the code flow is. Assuming your code is actually equivalent to:

```
for(int i=n; i>0; i/=2) {
  if(f()<=g()) {
    for(int j=f()*f(); j<n; j++) {
      f();
    }
   }
}
```

You need to find the best and the worst case performance.

IMHO it is easier to go from inside to the outside (at least until you get more experience):

1. The inner-most call `f()` is `O(log(n))` in the worst case and `O(1)` in the best case.
2. Since `f()*f()` is a constant the inner loop is `O(n)` ***times*** the previous step (which is `f()`) + 2 times `f()` for the initial value of `j` + there are also `O(n)` condition checks and `O(n)` increments which together can be expressed as a single `O(n)`.  So for the worst case it is `O(n*log(n) + 2*log(n) + n)` which is `O(n*log(n))` and for the best case it is `O(n*1 + 2 + n)` which is `O(n)`
3. The `if` itself is just time of the calculation of `f()` and `g()`. Since the condition is mostly true, we just add the cost of the inner loop. So for the worst case it is `O(log(n) + n + n*log(n))` which is `O(n*log(n))` and for the best case it is `O(1 + log^2(n) + n)` which is `O(n)` (`O(n)` dominates `O(log^2(n))`)
4. The outer loop as you correctly noticed is always `O(log(n))` ***times***. So the total complexity is `O(log(n))` ***times*** of the body (+ not forget about the check and increment, this might make a difference if the condition is mostly false). So the worst case is `O(log(n)*n*log(n)+log(n))` which is `O(n*log^2(n))` and the best case is `O(log(n)*n + log(n))` which is `O(n*log(n))`.

Hopefully I didn't mess up with details. But the most important thing is to understand when to add an when to multiply; and to understand which part dominates the others when you simplify.

Comment: Thank you so much but if you have a time can you see my another question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54177166/find-a-upper-and-lower-bound-of-following-code