# Find an upper and lower bound of following code

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory

I need to find a closest upper and lower bound of following code. I am beeginer in this so sorry for my mistake.

Upper bound for p() is O(log(n)), and lower bound is O(1)

Upper bound for notp() is O(log(n)), and lower bound is O(1)

I think that lower bound is O(1) because if I have n=4 then I get in the loop and since n%i==0 I call p() and it notice that is not a prime number so O(1) then since i=2 the other notp would not be executed. That is bast case scenario.

Worst case scenario that I go through loop so that log(n), and execute a p and a upper bound is O(log(n)) so it is O(log(n)^2) but I am not so sure that this is good, please tell me where I made a mistake?

```
int i;
for (i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) {
  if (n % i == 0) {
    p();
    break;
  }
}
if(i*i > n)
  notp();
```

Comment: The worst case is O(sqrt(N) * log N)

Comment: Can you explain to me that sqrt(N) because i never saw it?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by upper and lower bound? The "closest upper bound" would be normally the same as the "closest lower bound".

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54162589/how-to-find-a-upper-and-lower-bound-of-code/54165220#54165220

Comment: here is example where you can understand

Comment: The `for` loop runs for the worst case of `sqrt(N)` times. And each time, it calls p() for `log N` time. So it is `O(sqrt(N) * log N)` You can safely ignore the last and only call to `notp()` because it contributes only `log N` time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For order calculations, you would normally multiply them together when there is a loop.

```
for( i = 0; i < n ; i++ ){
     DoSomething(i);
}
```

That would be O(n), as the loop is a single case.

A nested loop would be

```
for( i = 0; i < n ; i++ ){ 
    for( j =0; j < n; j++ ){
       DoSomething(i,j);
    }
}
```

That becomes O( n^2 ) as they are additive.

If you have non-nested loops...

```
for( i = 0; i < n ; i++ ){
     DoSomething(i);
}


for( j = 0; j < sqrt(n) ; j++ ){
     DoSomething(j);
}
```

Then the O( x ), is the largest term.  That is because for very large n, the smaller values of x don't matter.

So you have a loop in your case, which is O( sqrt( n ) ).  That is because it is limited by i *i being less than n.

Then either one of p() or notp() will be called.

(I think p() and notp() are the wrong way round).

Re-factoring your code....

```
int i;
for (i = 2; i*i <= n; i++) {
  if (n % i == 0) {
    /* p(); */
    break;
  }
}
if(i*i > n)
  notp();
else
  p();
```

So we have the O( sqrt(n) ) time plus either of the p / notp functions which are O( log(n) )

O( sqrt(n ) + log(n) )

As the sqrt grows faster than  n, it overpowers the log(n) [wikipedia Big O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), leaving it as the final value.

O( sqrt(n) )

Answer (score 1):

As the termination condition of the loop is `i*i <= n`, the most possible number of iteration of the loop is `sqrt(n)`. As there is a `break` in the condition of `n % i == 0`, the worst case of this part is `sqrt(n) + log(n)` which is `O(sqrt(n))`. Also, eighter the second condition is true or not, as the worst case of `nopt()` is `O(log(n))`, the worst case of the algorithm in total is `O(sqrt(n))`.